# Problem with input and output shapes in Flatten() layer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a basic Convolutional Neural Network for image classification. I have a dataset of images belonging to 4 classes. I created Tensorflow datasets using `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory`:

```
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2
)

val_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)

train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    dataset_source, 
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True,
    subset='training'
) 

val_data = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    dataset_source, 
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False,
    subset='validation'
)
```

An example of architecture of my CNN that I tested is trivial and looks as follows:

```
image_shape = (299, 299, 3)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=image_shape))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4))

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
             optimizer = "adam",
             metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

Whenever I try to start training using `model.fit(train_data, epochs=100, validation_data = val_data)`, I receive the following error related to `Flatten()` layer:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 7372800 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 645248
[[node sequential_1/flatten_1/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-9-d01204576b1d>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1823]
```

I checked it using various versions of CNN, even the simplest containing single convolution layers, but the error occurs every time, only with different values. It's probably quite obvious but despite many tries I am not able to solve it, so I will be very thankful for any directions how to deal with my issue.

Comment: Are all the images in your dataset, of the same size?

Comment: Yes, they all have the same dimensions: 299 x 299

Comment: just as a quick diagnostic, can you try adding `target_size=(299, 299)` to your flow_from_directory calls?

Comment: @Vadim : I added it and this solved the problem. thank you, I didn't expect this would be that simple!

Comment: ggs. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `flow_from_directory` calls without specifying a `target_size` is just asking for trouble, because even a single wrongly-sized input will mess up your model fitting process. Simple fix is to add `target_size=(299, 299)` to the calls just to be safe (as seen in comment).

Also, consider adding `image_shape = (299, 299, 3)` above the `flow_from_directory` calls and specifying `target_size = image_shape[:-1]` to just pull it from there. This will make modifying `image_shape` easier, which you may want to do to experiment with various input size scalings.